# Required values of imported type don't show in list of "Example values"

Tags: swagger, symfony4, api-platform.com

I wonder what I omitted so that Swagger is not exposing public object values of type `Misd\PhoneNumberBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\PhoneNumberType` in the list of example values? The example values when POSTing an object are as follows, despite having another public object value:

[The Swagger interface showing example values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gL2y7.png)

```
[
  {
    "username": "string",
    "password": "string",
    "id": 0
  }
]
```

I can manually add the field and everything works fine (the value gets posted), but it's not ideal since a required value is not listed by the documentation.

```
  /**
   * @AssertPhoneNumber(defaultRegion="US", message="Please specify a valid mobile phone number", type="mobile")
   * @Assert\NotBlank
   * @ORM\Column(name="phone_number", type="phone_number", unique=true)
   */
  public $phoneNumber;
```

What am I missing? Looking forward to getting hints on this, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying the ApiProperty as an annotation solved my problem. Simply `use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty` and annotate the phone number property as follows:

```
  /**
   * @ApiProperty(
   *     attributes={
   *         "swagger_context"={
   *             "type"="string"
   *         }
   *     }
   * )
   * @AssertPhoneNumber(defaultRegion="US", message="Please specify a valid mobile phone number", type="mobile")
   * @Assert\NotBlank
   * @ORM\Column(name="phone_number", type="phone_number", unique=true)
   */
  public $phoneNumber;
```